# moving a row to another sheet based on category of the row

Tags: excel, vba

I manage to send a row from one sheet to another sheet but I need help in moving a row to another sheet based on the row category

i don't know if this clear enough but please let me know if it isn't.

```
Sub MoveBasedonValue() 

Dim xRg As Range
Dim xCell As Range
Dim A As Long
Dim B As Long
Dim C As Long 

A = Worksheets("master").UsedRange.Rows.Count
B = Worksheets("completed").UsedRange.Rows.Count 

If B = 1 Then
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("completed").UsedRange) = 0 Then B = 0
End If
Set xRg = Worksheets("master").Range("D1:D" & A)

On Error Resume Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For C = 1 To xRg.Count
    If CStr(xRg(C).Value) = "Done" Then
        xRg(C).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("completed").Range("A" & B + 1)
        xRg(C).EntireRow.Delete
        If CStr(xRg(C).Value) = "Done" Then
            C = C - 1
        End If
        B = B + 1
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this the code that "works-but-not-doing-everything-you-like" or is this a code that is "trying-to-do-what-you-like-but-isn't-working"? If it's the first, you need to elaborate on "row category" and what exactly you are trying to do. If it's the latter, please tell us what isn't working and what exactly you need help with. Example input and expected output is very helpful data to understand the question quickly.

Answer (score 0):

When deleting rows it's best to work from the bottom to the top:

```
For C = xRg.Count To 1 Step -1 
    If xRg(C).Value = "Done" Then
        With xRg(C).EntireRow
            .Copy Destination:=Worksheets("completed").Range("A" & B + 1)
            .Delete
            B = B + 1
        End With
    End If
Next
```